# Isn't it possible to create two different AppModule with NestJS?

Tags: nestjs

For normal usage, it works well with app.module.ts and main.ts.

app.module.ts

```js
    import { MiddlewareConsumer, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
    import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
    import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
    import jwt from 'express-jwt';

    import config from './config';

    @Module({
      imports: [
        ConfigModule.forRoot({
          isGlobal: true,
          load: [config],
          envFilePath: '.env',
        }),
        TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
          inject: [ConfigService],
          useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({ ...configService.get('db') }),
        }),
        GraphqlModule,
      ],
      controllers: [],
    })
    export class AppModule {
      constructor(private config: ConfigService) {}

      configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
        consumer
          .forRoutes('graphql');
      }
    }
```

main.ts

```js
    import { INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common';
    import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
    import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
    import compression from 'compression';
    import { createConnection } from 'typeorm';

    import { AppModule } from './app.module';

    async function bootstrap() {
      const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
      app.use(compression());

      const config = app.get(ConfigService);

      if (config.get('pubsub.enable')) {
        const pubsubConnection = await createConnection(
          Object.assign(config.get('db'), { name: 'pubsub' }),
        );
        .....
      }

      useContainer(app.select(AppModule), { fallbackOnErrors: true });

      const server = await app.listen(config.get('PORT', ''));
      server.setTimeout(3 * 60 * 1000);
    }

    bootstrap();
```

---

But if add another app.test.module.ts with a new name

app.test.module.ts

```js
    import { MiddlewareConsumer, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
    import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
    import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
    import jwt from 'express-jwt';

    import config from './config';

    @Module({
      imports: [
        ConfigModule.forRoot({
          isGlobal: true,
          load: [config],
          envFilePath: '.env.test',
        }),
        TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
          inject: [ConfigService],
          useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({ ...configService.get('db') }),
        }),
        GraphqlModule,
      ],
      controllers: [],
    })
    export class AppTestModule {
      constructor(private config: ConfigService) {}

      configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
        consumer
          .forRoutes('graphql');
      }
    }
```

It will fail when db connection. It said can't find the default connection name but it exists in the config.ts.

In the main.ts, it only importing `AppModule` class but why can't work well for the whole application?

Some NestJS related packages:

```js
      "dependencies": {
        "@nestjs/cli": "^8.2.6",
        "@nestjs/common": "^8.4.5",
        "@nestjs/config": "^2.0.1",
        "@nestjs/core": "^8.4.5",
        "@nestjs/graphql": "^9.1.1",
        "@nestjs/platform-express": "^8.4.5",
        "@nestjs/swagger": "^5.2.1",
        "@nestjs/typeorm": "^8.0.2",
      "devDependencies": {
        "@nestjs/testing": "^8.4.7",
```

Comment: could you show your dependencies and dev dependencies?

Comment: @MicaelLevi I added some NestJS related packages to the end of the question.